# Are there any good email management systems that will allow me to get a list of 'sent-to' email addresses from a large list of bounceback emails?

Tags: email-bounces

The basic idea is that I sent a newsletter with a bespoke bulkmailer and got a load of 'bouncedback' or 'message sending failed' emails, and I'm trying to just get a long list of 'sent-to' email addresses from this list so I can go over them easily and check for mistakes etc.

I've tried  [Popmonger](http://www.popmonger.com/) but it doesn't detect bounceback emails very well, with only a roughly 70% success rate.

It allows you to specify rules, eg to search for emails with the string

```
* failure *
```

or

```
* bounced *
```

(with asterisks as wildcards), but this isn't implemented very well, and as a result, after hours of experimentation, I've given up.

Are there any options out there for doing the same sort of task?

Thanks in advance Super User!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ListRocket will give you exactly what you're looking for.

You can see your list in any way you want.

If you want to see everyone that was a "Hard Bounce" you can , you can even click on each entry and edit it right there. You can also sort your soft bounces and create auto responders to resend to them!  So you can it automatically 3 days later resend an email that "Soft" bounced due to a "Full Mailbox" to only the SofBounced addresses!  It's awesome.

Once you sort by whatever criteria you choose, it will give you the list of emails, again, fully editable.

ListRocket offers a FREE Account to try it all out! http://www.listrocket.com